# Looking for a combinatorial problem definition

Tags: math, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We are given "N" pairs of parentheses, ie "N" opening parenthesis "(" and "N" closing parenthesis ")". We are asked to find the number of ways to make Sequence of 2N parentheses **that are GOOD**, *i.e. we dont close before opening.*

I need to find a definition for **GOOD Sequences** that i can use for the rest of the problem.

Comment: This is technically the same question as `the number of distinct binary search trees containing n nodes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catalan numbers!

Comment: You could have added a link in for the lazy. ;-)

Comment: The best presentation of Catalan numbers that I know of is the one in *The Book of Numbers* by Conway and Guy. On pages 101–104 they explain the connection between frieze patterns, polygon dissections, binary trees, exponentiations, rooted bushes, and parenthesized expressions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number seems to be a suitable online reference. Certainly interesting to me and does explitcly mention the problem above.

Comment: Exactly! by doing a search on google, i got the wiki page about catalan number and the problem is mentioned there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Richard Stanley maintains a list of all (150+) known objects counted by the Catalan numbers: http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/catadd.pdf